# SweetAlert Issues

Tags: html, sweetalert2

I've been trying to use SweetAlert in HTML, and for some reason, it's not recognizing swal() as a function. It's just putting it as text onto the he page. I'm extremely new to HTML, as Lua and Node.js are my primary languages.

This is what appears on the page.

```
swal("test", { icon: "warning", });
```

Code:

```html
<html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
  swal("test", {
          icon: "warning",
        });
</html>
```

If anyone with more experience in HTML is able to point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript, when inside of an HTML file, should be enclosed in `<script></script>` tags. You also need to include a `head` section, so your HTML will look something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
     swal('test', {icon: 'warning'});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I enclosed it in that tag, and the text has disappeared, but still no alert. Just a blank page.

Comment: What does your complete code look like now? I tried it on my end and it works just fine

Comment: ```
<html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  swal("test", {
          icon: "warning",
        });
      </script>
</html>
```

I don't know if I was supposed to do any installation or anything with Npm prior to this.

Comment: Actually, I think I know what the issue is. You should enclose your first `script` tags inside of a `head` tag, otherwise your webpage won't load in time for the external script to load. I've edited my answer above

Comment: So, like this?

```js
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <script>
  swal("test", {
          icon: "warning",
        });
      </script>
</html>
```

(Sorry about the formatting there it won't let me use the ``` thing)

Comment: Yep, I'd also put your second `script` tag and JavaScript inside of a `body` tag.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried it and it worked perfectly. I appreciate the help!